# passing info from two text fields to a function with one GUI button push in Maya

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

In Maya, using Python, I want to create a simple GUI that holds two text fields and one button. When the button is pressed I would like the input from the two text fields to be passed to another function where the data can be manipulated and acted upon.

Example:

"name1" , "name2"
button

```
def edit(name1, name2):
    print "name 1 and name2 = " + name1 + name2
```

When the button is pressed, the info from name 1 and 2 would be passed to the function, edit where it can be used.

What is the easiest logic to accomplish this using Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is querying the text value from the textfields on button press.

Example how to do it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def createWindow():

    windowID = 'window'


    if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI('window')

    window = cmds.window(windowID)
    cmds.rowColumnLayout()

    cmds.textFieldGrp('textField_A', label = 'Textfield A: ')
    cmds.textFieldGrp('textField_B', label = 'Textfeild B: ' )

    cmds.button(label = 'pass textfield values', command = queryTextField)

    cmds.showWindow( window )

def queryTextField(*args):

    text_A = cmds.textFieldGrp( 'textField_A', query = True, text = True)
    text_B = cmds.textFieldGrp( 'textField_B', query = True, text = True)

   print text_A, text_B

createWindow()
```

You query the value of a textfield or a textfieldGrp with the following line.

```
text_A = cmds.textFieldGrp( 'textField_A', query = True, text = True)
```